# App Signing in Xcode - Provisioning Profile issue

Tags: ios, certificate, xcode8, provisioning-profile, ipa

I have a certificate that was sent to me (Cert A). I am trying to export a .ipa from the organizer in xcode 8. I have set the application for manual signing and xcode recognizes Cert A. However, when I go to export, it gives me an error saying "No matching provisioning profiles found." This is after I select "Use local signing assets." The profile I am attempting to sign with was sent to me so it's not associated with my personal developer account (Cert B). When I try to export using Cert B, it works fine. So my question, in multiple parts, is how do I export using the provisioning profile (Cert A)? Do I need the team log in and add to accounts preferences? Is there another way for me to export the .ipa that would allow for the Cert A to sign the application? The Bundle ID is correct as well.

Comment: So you did get a provisioning profile with Cert A? Are you using a wildcard app I'd for one of the profiles?  Otherwise, you can't have the same id tied to the account associated with cert B as with the account for cert A. Also, did you get the private key for Cert A? If not, it's not a valid signing identity.

Comment: I did get a provisioning profile with Cert A and in build settings, it's set up with no issues. In my keychain, I see the private key for the cert as well.

Comment: What type of profile is it? Distribution? Development? You'll probably need to provide screenshots of your projects code signing settings.

Comment: I was told it was distribution. I'm going to add pictures as soon as I can to illustrate.

Comment: Update: I ended up having to be added to development team in order to export.

Comment: So you must have been using automatic code signing?

Comment: I wasn't, I had that turned off. But for some reason, when I went to export if wouldn't allow the for the signing I put in. When I was added to the group, it finally allowed me to export.